# Requesting change of team

Tags: human-resources, job-satisfaction

I am graduating this year from university (United States), and have a job offer at a large scale software company. I was an intern at this company this past summer and I was not a huge fan of being a part of my team. They are all great people individually, but the team environment left a lot to desire (think: nobody eats lunch together, team mentality is to get in, do work, go home).

I have friends who interned / work at this company, and they have very vibrant team environments that sound like a bunch of friends working together. In fact, the company is pushing the culture towards this paradigm. I just happened to land in a team that is a little behind the times.

I have already signed the offer because offer deadlines are brutal, but I have been dreading going back to that team ever since. I have been thinking about asking the HR if I can move teams before starting at the company next year. The problem is that the offer is tied to my team specifically.

Question: if I email HR about a change of team request, will my manager know?

Comment: What's your actual question? Note that questions asking "what to do" are [off-topic](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: Sorry, I have clarified my post to have a question.

Comment: You seem to have replaced a "what to do" question with a "how does this company work" question. We have no way of knowing whether HR would inform the manager, and/or under what circumstances.

Comment: @ChrisG while that's true, I can't imagine a situation in which HR wouldn't talk to the hiring manger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: if I email HR about a change of team request, will my
>   manager know?

**Yes, your manager will know.**

You are on the hiring plan to start at a certain date in the future. If you request not to be on that team, the manager must be notified so that they can find someone else to fill that role.

Your mistake was in accepting a position that you don't want. "Dreading going back to that team" should have been the clue.

Instead, you should have thanked them for the offer, but indicated that while you love the company, you'd like to start out with a different team. (You wouldn't need to get too specific about the reasons). You may have very well ended up with a good internal recommendation, assuming your internship work was well-regarded.

Now you are in a rather awkward position.

You could withdraw your acceptance and apply for an open position on another team (if one exists). Or you could notify HR and just hope for the best.

Comment: You're right, I definitely should have done as you said and asked for a different team. I will keep that in mind in future employment opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes very likely the manager would be told of and have to approve a change of team. After all they are hiring you where they have a vacant position and if you change teams, then he will not have the expected person to fill that role.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: if I email HR about a change of team request, will my manager know?

Your manager approves your time sheets, evaluates your performance and supervises your team. And you think that there is a way to change teams without your manager eventually being in the loop? Me think you very funny :)

The only way your manager won't know is when they say get run over by a bus just before they get notified that you are applying to change teams.

Comment: Haha, had to laugh because of your last sentence.